# How to get reproducible results from XGBoostRegressor? random_state has no effect

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

I realized that, contrary to scikit learn, setting a fixed value for `random_state` does not guarantee that the model will output the same results everytime.

Hence I'm not able to get reproducible results from XGBoostRegressor, even by setting `seed`, `random_state`, `colsample_bytree` and `subsample`.

Is this a bug? Is this somewhat by design? If so, why?

**If you have a solution or a workaround that always works, please share.**

Here's the code:

```
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05,
                     subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree= 0.8, seed=42)

model.fit(X_train_trf,y_train,
        early_stopping_rounds=5,
        eval_set=[(X_train_trf, y_train), (X_valid_trf, y_valid)],
        verbose=False)
preds = model.predict(X_valid_trf)
```

Comment: Is this an 'early stopping' issue? If you post a minimal reproducible example we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok I will add it today

Comment: Or can you give me an example of code for a reproducible XGBoost model?

Comment: Changing `subsample` and `colsample_bytree ` to '1' and increasing `early_stopping_rounds` to '1000' (or whatever n_estimators is set to) should do the trick - let me know if this solves your problem or not.

Comment: Why `early_stopping_rounds` to 1000, doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of using `early_stopping_rounds` though?

Comment: Still not reproducible. Ran it 3 times and got 3 different results for 'mean absolute error'. Also mote, if that's relevant, that I'm running this in a Python notebook in Kaggle (although this makes no difference when using sklearn).

Comment: How different are your results? Slight differences could be explained by non-determinism in floating point summation order and multi-threading but overall gradient boosting doesn't really allow you to build models reproducibly. You can control a lot of the randomness by tweaking the parameters (e.g. the suggestions I made above), but overall you expect some variation in the final model if the signal in the data isn't strong. Sorry I can't be more help with this - in my own experience I get the same model every time using the methods outlined -> I guess it depends on the data you're analysing

Comment: Yea ok thanks for trying. I get MAE: 15410 the first run, then 18179, then 18644, then 17348, then 17798, then 15822.... It's quite all over the place it seems

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the issue was not so much with XGBoost but with the data splitting.

I was splitting the data with `train_test_split` without setting the `random_state`, which caused some randomness.

Fixed as below:

```
X_train_full, X_valid_full, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_full, y,
  train_size=0.8, test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, slight differences could be explained by non-determinism in floating point summation order and multi-threading but overall gradient boosting doesn't really lend itself to building models reproducibly. You can control a lot of the randomness by tweaking the parameters (e.g. setting random_state, seed, input features, model params, and the suggestions I made in the comments above), but overall you expect some small variations when building models due to how the algorithm works; especially if the signal in the data isn't strong.